# How to handle Not Found Resource?

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

when i try to visit a deleted image url i got this :

```
The requested resource /storage/images/5865c6789d48d96dd04ad92e7f7.jpeg was not found on this server.
```

So how can i handle this error or exception, so i can return formatted json instead.

I tried to handle `FileNotFoundException` at `app\Exceptions\Handler` but it didn't work

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
  if ($exception instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
    dd(json_encode['message'=>'file not found']);
  }

    parent::report($exception);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you generating this URL?

Comment: Have you imported  `FileNotFoundException` correctly as `\Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: When you say "It didn't work" how didn't it work?

Comment: @AmitGupta By using Storage::url();

Comment: @RossWilson Yes i did but it still not working

Comment: @RossWilson i tried to visit the file link in postman and it gave me that error

Comment: I have the same issue. for me this part $exception instanceof FileNotFoundException is returning false even with a FileNotFoundException.